# Consume messages from RabbitMQ queue using spring cloud stream 3.0+

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

I have a Producer producing messages in a RabbitMQ queue by using a direct exchange.

queue name: **TEMP_QUEUE**,
exchange name: **TEMP_DIRECT_EXCHANGE**

Producing to this queue is easy since on my producer application I use [Spring AMQP](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) which I am familiar with.

On my Consumer application, I need to use [Spring cloud stream](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream) version 3.0+.

I want to avoid using legacy annotations like `@EnableBinding`, `@StreamListener` because they are about to be depracated.

Legacy code for my application would look like that :

```
@EnableBinding(Bindings.class)
public class TempConsumer {

    @StreamListener(target = "TEMP_QUEUE")
    public void consumeFromTempQueue(MyObject object) {
        // do stuff with the object
    }
}

public interface Bindings {
    @Input("TEMP_QUEUE")
    SubscribableChannel myInputBinding();
}
```

From their docs I have found out I can do something like that

```
@Bean
public Consumer<MyObject> consumeFromTempQueue() {
    return obj -> {
        // do stuff with the object
    };
}
```

It is not clear to me how do I specify that this bean will consume from **TEMP_QUEUE**? Also what if I want to consume from multiple queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Consuming from Existing Queues/Exchanges](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges).

You can consume from multiple queues with

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumeFromTempQueue-in-0.destination=q1,q2,q3
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer.multiplex=true
```

Without multiplex you'll get 3 bindings; with multiplex, you'll get 1 listener container listening to multiple queues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `application.yml` to bind your bean.

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  function.definition: consumeFromTempQueue
```

You can use this configuration to configure source, process and sink as well. In your case you are just using a source.

You can read this [post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/07/20/introducing-java-functions-for-spring-cloud-stream-applications-part-1) for more information.